# updating updatepanel's based on texbox focus lost in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net page with two user controls. Each of which are in separate updatepanel's One user control has three textboxes. I want to update the second updatepanel based on change of text/ focus out in first user control. How can I access both user control's textboxes, and other controls in page and update the updatepanel on change of text ?

```
updatepanel1
 user control1
   textbox1
   textbox2
   textbox3

updatepane2
  usercontrol2
  label1
```

Regards,
Asif Hameed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoa, UpdatePanels!  That takes me back.  Triggering UpdatePanels to "postback" asynchronously from the client has always been a bit of a kludge.  The common way was to register an AsyncPostBackTrigger with a hidden button's click event and then explicitly call its click event on the client side.  However, a solution with a few less layers of indirection is to call the ASP.NET AJAX library's __doPostback() JS function.

Assuming you're using jQuery (which may be far-fetched considering you're still using UpdatePanels!), you can add an event handler to the 'focusout' event of your UserControl1 to trigger the asynchronous postback of your UpdatePanel2.  I would recommend putting this JS outside of one of your UpdatePanels.

```
$('#userControl1').on('focusout', function() {
  __doPostback('UpdatePanel2UniqueId', '');
});
```

I dug up a good article that explains the technique of using __doPostback in a bit more detail.

[Easily refresh an UpdatePanel, using JavaScript](http://encosia.com/easily-refresh-an-updatepanel-using-javascript/)